# DataTables - display a button in a cell of every row

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, laravel-5.1

I'm using the [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin and within the initialization I'm using the `"drawCallback"` to make changes to the look of the rows.

My code is as follows:

```
        "drawCallback": function() {
            table.rows().every( function() {
                var d = this.data();
                var option = this.find('.options');

                if (d.activated) {
                    option.html('<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary pull-right"> Enabled</button>');
                } else {
                    option.html('<button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right"> Disabled</button>');
                }
            });

         }
```

However the `this.find('.options')` part isn't doing anything.

Essentially I want to:

1. get the current row
2. select the column I've given the className of 'options'
3. insert a button there relevant to the row data

HTML:

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

DataTables initialisation:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   columns: [
        {
            "className":      'center',
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            data: 'last_name'
        },
        {
            data: 'first_name'
        },
        {
            data: 'email'
        },
        {
            "className":      'options',
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        }
    ],

    // ...and so on
```

Originally I had the following code which worked:

```
$('td.options').html('<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary pull-right"> Enabled</button>');
```

but this was indiscriminate of the row data and simply pasted the same button for each row.

Comment: Can you add some html with the specified class in it? I.e. The HTML output

Comment: @SamSwift I've added some further context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to define a function producing content for the cell.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   columns: [
        {
            "className":      'center',
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {   "data": 'last_name' },
        {   "data": 'first_name' },
        {   "data": 'email'  },
        {
            "className":      'options',
            "data":           null,
            "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
               if (full.activated) {
                   return '<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary pull-right"> Enabled</button>';
               } else {
                   return '<button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right"> Disabled</button>';
               }
            }
        }
    ],

    // ...and so on

});
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. I originally had it in the callback because plenty of operations were causing the table to redraw but I hadn't read up on the render method. Can't fault it. Many thanks!